# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade from 13.10

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I would like to ask about upgrade of 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04.

When I type in CL `sudo update-manager` after finding new version and beginning of an upgrade dialog appears saying:

Free translation:

```
Cannot calculate upgrade
Unsolvable error

It could be  due:
upgrading to devel release
upgrading from devel release
unofficial software packages
```

First one is not true, second neither, I am not using many unofficial packages.

What to do?

Comment: Check this guide: http://askubuntu.com/questions/458201/how-can-i-upgrade-ubuntu-to-newer-release-manually-without-using-update-manager

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove or diable all non-official repositories ("PPA's") to perform the upgrade.

To do this, open *Software & Updates*, navigate to *Other Software* (2nd tab) and untick all entries.

E.g. the Google Chrome PPA: `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`

after the Upgrade you can re-enable them, but first you have to update the distro version. Select every PPA, click *Edit* and set the field *Distribution* to `trusty`.

Some PPA's may not work for Trusty because they aren't updated yet or discontinued. You'll get an error report if this is the case when reloading the APT sources. You have to remove these PPA's to prevent further errors.

Comment: I have disabled everything I could, but still the error remains....

Answer (score 0):

Open the apt log to see what happened. It should be in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`.

Many times it have a line with ERROR and a concrete package that is causing the problems.