# 13.10 to 14.04 Cannot calculate the upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I tried to upgrade 64 bit UBUNTU 13.10 to 14.04. I have an AMD Phenom II X4 810 Processor x 4, 7GB memory, GeForce 9800 GTX+/PCIe/SSE2 graphics, 960 GB hd (3.4 % full.)

I didn't have just one error..it looks like 31 packages were broken.  The log is 33 pages long but here is where the repair looks like it tried to start:

```
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 31
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 31
Investigating (0) libqt5core5a [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14 > ( libs )
Broken libqt5core5a:amd64 Breaks on libqt5core5 [ amd64 ] < 5.0.2+dfsg1-7ubuntu11.1 > ( libs ) (< 5.2.0+dfsg~)
  Considering libqt5core5:amd64 0 as a solution to libqt5core5a:amd64 416
  Added libqt5core5:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libqt5core5a:amd64 via remove of libqt5core5:amd64
MarkDelete libqt5core5 [ amd64 ] < 5.0.2+dfsg1-7ubuntu11.1 > ( libs ) FU=0
```

I just copied all the 'Broken' lines.  The other lines were pretty similar for the most part.  I didn't think I should paste all 33 pages here.

```
Broken libharfbuzz0b:amd64 Conflicts on libharfbuzz0a [ amd64 ] < 0.9.19-1 > ( libs )
Broken libharfbuzz0b:amd64 Conflicts on libharfbuzz0a [ i386 ] < 0.9.19-1 > ( libs )
Broken cups-filters:amd64 Conflicts on foomatic-filters [ amd64 ] < 4.0.17-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/text )
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:amd64 Breaks on libcogl12 [ amd64 ] < 1.14.0-2 > ( libs )
Broken unity-control-center:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-control-center-unity [ amd64 ] < 1.3+13.10.20131004-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken libgoa-1.0-0b:amd64 Conflicts on libgoa-1.0-0 [ amd64 ] < 3.8.3-2 > ( libs )
Broken unity-control-center-signon:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-control-center-signon [ amd64 ] < 0.1.7~+13.10.20130724.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken libunity-core-6.0-9:amd64 Conflicts on libunity-core-6.0-8 [ amd64 ] < 7.1.2+13.10.20131014.1-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libunity-core-6.0-9:amd64 Conflicts on unity-common [ amd64 ] < none | 7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken libaqbanking34-plugins:amd64 Conflicts on libaqbanking-plugins-libgwenhywfar60 [ amd64 ] < 5.0.28beta-1 > ( libs ) (< 5.3.5beta)
 Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 Conflicts on jockey-common [ amd64 ] < 0.9.7-0ubuntu15 > ( admin )
Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 Conflicts on jockey-common [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 Conflicts on jockey-gtk [ amd64 ] < 0.9.7-0ubuntu15 > ( oldlibs )
Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 Conflicts on jockey-gtk [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libmono-wcf3.0a-cil:amd64 Conflicts on libmono-wcf3.0-cil [ amd64 ] < 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 > ( cli-mono ) (< 3.2.3)
Broken wine1.6-amd64:amd64 Depends on libopencl-1.1-1 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libdb-java:amd64 Conflicts on libdb5.1-java [ amd64 ] < 5.1.29-7 -> 5.1.29-7ubuntu1 > ( universe/java )
Broken wine1.4-amd64:amd64 Depends on wine1.6-amd64 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine1.6-i386:i386 Depends on libopencl-1.1-1 [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken wine1.4-i386:i386 Depends on wine1.6-i386 [ i386 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libmutter0c:amd64 Conflicts on libmutter0b [ amd64 ] < 3.8.4-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libgjs0e:amd64 Conflicts on libgjs0d [ amd64 ] < 1.37.6-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libmono-csharp4.0c-cil:amd64 Conflicts on libmono-csharp4.0-cil [ amd64 ] < 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 > ( cli-mono ) (< 3.2.1)
Broken libdb5.1-java-gcj:amd64 Depends on libdb5.1-java [ amd64 ] < 5.1.29-7 -> 5.1.29-7ubuntu1 > ( universe/java ) (= 5.1.29-7ubuntu1)
Broken wine1.6:amd64 Depends on wine1.6-amd64 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs ) (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libcogl-pango12:amd64 Depends on libcogl12 [ amd64 ] < 1.14.0-2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.13.4)
Broken libvlccore5:amd64 Depends on vlc-data [ amd64 ] < 2.0.8-1 -> 2.1.2-2build2 > ( universe/graphics ) (= 2.0.8-1)
Broken libperl5.14:amd64 Depends on perl-base [ amd64 ] < 5.14.2-21build1 -> 5.18.2-2ubuntu1 > ( perl ) (= 5.14.2-21build1)
Broken libubuntudownloadmanager1:amd64 Depends on libqt5core5 [ amd64 ] < 5.0.2+dfsg1-7ubuntu11.1 > ( libs ) (>= 5.0.2)
Broken libmirserver7:amd64 Depends on libmirplatform [ amd64 ] < 0.0.15+13.10.20131014-0ubuntu1 -> 0.1.8+14.04.20140411-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 0.0.15+13.10.20131014-0ubuntu1)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140505.be1469cc-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140507.18416b51-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken wine1.4:amd64 Depends on wine1.6 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140505.be1469cc-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140507.18416b51-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140505.be1469cc-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140505.be1469cc-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140507.18416b51-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140505.be1469cc-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140507.18416b51-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl [ amd64 ] < 0.6.0+git20140313.a4fbc773-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-radeon [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140505.be1469cc-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-15 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-15 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
 Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Broken xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64  ] < none > ( none )
  Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64  ] < none > ( none )
  Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [  amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140505.be1469cc-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
  Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140507.18416b51-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
```

And the final entry:

```
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Considering xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 10004 as a solution to xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 10004
Considering xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 10004 as a solution to xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 10004
Done
```

I know that xserver is a video driver and I have an Nvidia video card which has been challenging on pretty much every upgrade I have done.  It has never done this before.

One common suggestion is to disable all third-party ppas.    I uncheck them and hit OK and try the upgrade.   When I open up the Software and Updates window after trying the Upgrade, all the ppas are checked again.

Anything pop out at someone?  I haven't loaded most of the apps it says are broken..with the exception of xserver.  I just do all recommended updates when they come up. Xserver I have pretty much gotten working with trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  The first answer looked a lot like my post.  I found it [Unable to upgrade to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449691/unable-to-upgrade-to-14-04?rq=1) as well as referred to in at least one other post.

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-all
```

and that did it.  Thanks to [Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade from 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450526/ubuntu-14-04-upgrade-from-13-10?rq=1) I next ran this:

```
sudo apt-get  update
sudo apt-get  upgrade
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

and a few others from the top 7, 10, 14 things you should do sites. I even have an NVIDIA splash screen now!